# Change title with multi time on one view controller. Don't show "Back" title again with short title iOS Swift ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, swift2

I had two view controller. In view controller 2, I changed title with multi time. With "long" title, example "123123123123123123123", it hided "Back" title, it is okay. But when I changed "short" title, example "123", it didn't show "Back" title button. Please help me, how to show "Back" title button with "short" title

Step 1: navigation controller show short title. It also show "Back" title button

Step 2: Changed from short title to long title. It also hide "Back" title button. It is normal

Step 3: but when I changed again short title. It hided "Back" title button. Expected result it must show "Back" title button

Comment: Step 1: navigation controller show short title. It also show "Back" title button

Step 2: Changed from short title to long title. It also hide "Back" title button. It is normal

Step 3: but when I changed again short title. It hided "Back" title button. Expected result it must show "Back" title button

Comment: Sometimes it's better to edit your post instead of attaching comments.